# Is there a newer version of snort available?

Tags: apt, 10.04, ppa, snort

The Snort version available for Lucid is 2.8.5.2, for which snort rules are not available anymore. Is there a ppa for the updated version of snort or are there any good tutorials for installing snort from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Install via PPAs

The [linked PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ebf0/+archive/gamelinux?field.series_filter=lucid) has snort v2.9:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ebf0/gamelinux
sudo apt-get update
```

From my reading of the rules - any v2.9.x meets the rule standards - the .x are just stability updates.

Another PPA I've found is `ppa:hurricanedefense/testing` which contains v2.9.1 of snort.

As with all PPAs - these are for testing purposes and may make your system unstable.  Have a full image backup available.  You can also install `ppa-purge` to remove PPAs. N.B. enable the backports software source to install `ppa-purge`

### Install via compilation

**Data AcQuisition library**

Download some prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install flex bison  build-essential checkinstall libpcap0.8-dev libnet1-dev
```

Now download and extract the latest daq source code from snort.org

```
cd daq-0.6.1/
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
sudo dpkg -i daq_0.6.1-1_i386.deb
```

**Libdnet**

```
wget http://libdnet.googlecode.com/files/libdnet-1.12.tgz
tar xvfz libdnet-1.12.tgz
cd libdnet-1.12/
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
sudo dpkg -i libdnet_1.12-1_i386.deb
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libdnet.1.0.1 /usr/lib/libdnet.1
```

**Snort**

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev libmysqlclient15-dev
```

Now download and extract the latest snort source code from snort.org

```
cd snort-2.9.1
./configure --with-mysql --enable-build-dynamic-examples  --enable-gre --enable-reload --enable-linux-smp-stats --enable-zlib
make
sudo checkinstall
sudo dpkg -i snort_2.9.1-1_i386.deb

sudo ldconfig
```

At this point you need to configure the snort.conf file according to your environment.

[source](http://bailey.st/blog/2010/10/06/compiling-snort-2-9-0/)

Comment: The snort available at ppa:ebf0/gamelinux doesn't have ncurses based configuration tool. And I couldn't get snort work with multiple interfaces.

Comment: I added the second ppa with the commands you provided above. But it installs only the old snort from thr main repository.

Comment: I got this error while startng snort: `ERROR: parser.c(5260) Could not stat dynamic module path "/usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor/": No such file or directory.
Fatal Error, Quitting..`

Comment: make sure you remove the old  `snort` package first before compiling and installing the new `snort`.

Comment: I had purged the old one. But I solved this error by changing the path to: `/usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor/`. Antother error appeared now. It says there are some errors in the rules. So trying to get the new rules.

Comment: Somehow I got it working. This is what I have in my /etc/rc.local: `/usr/local/bin/snort -D -u snort -g snort -i any -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -l /var/log/snort/` In few hours the log dir got 500 MB in size. Is there a way to make just log the alerts or intrusions?

Comment: Excellent - well done - as to how to use - probably worth another question.  I will readily admit, I'm not an expert at configuring this.  Here is a useful step-by-step I've used in the past (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/snort-tutorial/) Probably your best bet is the snort forums at snort.org